# Form Submission Cloudflare Pages and Worker

Tags: html, forms, serverless, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am trying to develop a personal website, currently my hurdle is form submission and contact page management. How do I do a form submit on a personal site hosted on cloudflare pages to a serverless function on cloudflare workers with integration to slack or a webhook.  It just doesn't seem to make sense, Do you have anything in mind???:)

Answer (score 1):

Using a Cloudflare worker for form submission won't be too different from any other server side language.

The general idea is, you have an HTML form, and your target will be a URL. For Cloudflare workers, you'll probably want to set a `route` so you can use your own domain (e.g. `mysite.com/form-submit`).

Inside the worker's code, you'll be able to examine the incoming request, and execute whatever code you'd like. In your case, making an additional HTTP call to a slack webhook. This example may help with that -

https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/post-json